# What's the origin of the word "bunda"? Does the average Portuguese know what it means?

Tags: etimologia, diferenças-transatlânticas

I never heard it in Portugal. It seems to be typically Brazilian and my question is: when and where did "bunda" originate?

Edit: "bunda" = buttocks, butts.

Comment: What are the meaning of *bunda*?

Comment: Never heard _bunda_ in Portugal? Really?? How do portuguese call this part of the human body?

Comment: @gmauch I know but any other person who visit the site maybe don't knows.

Comment: @JorgeB. I'm really surprised that _bunda_ might not be well known in Portugal. In Brasil it is an absolutely common word. Children learn it as soon as they learn what is _perna_ or _braço_, or any other external part of the human body.

Comment: @gmauch rabo, cú, traseiro, nádegas, ânus, nalgas, pacote, pandeiro, cagueiro, ceira, and so on... there's no end to names for it, but bunda is not used much (despite everyone knowing the word).

Comment: Its also a common street word in punjab state of india and pakistan, they use it as bund but the meaning is same buttocks , don't know when and how it comes in india

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Houaiss dictionary ([paywall](http://houaiss.uol.com.br/busca?palavra=bunda)), it comes from the word *'mbunda* in [Kimbundu](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimbundu), a Bantu language from Angola, and occurs in Portuguese dictionaries since the early 19th century. Houaiss also mentions it's not completely unknown in Portugal, although it's not used there:

> a pal. está registrada no Novo Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa (1836), de Constâncio, como um angolismo, e no Grande Dicionário Português, de frei Domingos Vieira (1871), na acp. de 'nádegas de gente alcatreira', vale dizer, 'nadeguda'; em Portugal, entre os usuários atuais da língua, tal voc. não é desconhecido, mas não é empregado
>
> **Etimologia**
>
> quimb. 'mbunda 'quadris, nádegas'

Comment: "rabo", "cu", "padaria",

Comment: The word appears in the Dicionário das Ciências de Lisboa, not as a Brazillianism, and they quote: *Nada de fome, de frio, de ralhos e maus tratos, e muito menos de pontapés na **bunda** de ricos e tiranos/No hunger, no cold, no lecturing or beating, and abobe all no kicks in the **bunda** from rich folks or tyrants* ([Aquilino Ribeiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquilino_Ribeiro), *Malhadinhas*, 1922.) Aqulino Ribeiro was a portuguese writer.

Comment: Padaria?!! Hahahahaha!  @JorgeB.

Comment: Yes, padaria was used as a lighter word for "bunda", last century in Brazil. I haven't heard it for a long time.  Older people may still use it.

Comment: I'll start using *padaria*, as an effort to bring the word back to usage.

Comment: @bfav, tem que colocar no roteiro dalgum programa tipo Porta dos Fundos, jejejeje .... tenho que escutar o Toquinho explicando de novo pq me veio à cabeça "na tonga da milonga do cabuletê"